# Anchor point with ggplot geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a simple plot with `ggplot2` and I'd like to add a smoothed line that is anchored (fixed) at the first point. I used the trick described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12484/constrained-linear-regression-through-a-specified-point), but it looks like I need to readjust the fitted values by adding the difference `y[1] - predict(lm, data.frame(y=5))`. How do I do this? Is there a better way?

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(3)

d = data.frame(x=5:14)
d$y = log(d$x^2) + rnorm(10,0,2)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ poly(x,4), se=F) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = I(y-y[1]) ~ 0 + poly(x-x[1],4), se=F, color='red')
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Fit the model outside of ggplot, then get the predictions and the offset predictions in a dataframe and use geom_line to add this to the plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
m <- lm(I(y-y[1]) ~ 0 + poly(x-x[1],4), data=d) # model without intercept

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ poly(x,4), se=F) +
  geom_line(data=data.frame(x=d$x, 
  # the intercept is y[1] - poly(x)[1,]*coeff (it's not computed by lm)
  # y = prediction by the model    + the intercept
  y = poly(d$x,4)%*%m$coefficients + d$y[1]-as.numeric(poly(d$x,4)[1,]%*%m$coefficients)), 
  aes(x,y), color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. To make the red line smoother I suppose I should just increase the resolution of `x`